# Rails link_to calling incorrect controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

My rails link_to is calling a different controller action than it should. I have a dropdown menu that I would like to link_to another portion of the site. However, it calls the controller method that helped build the page instead of the actual controller method. This causes a problem because I don't pass in the correct information into the method call to properly execute that. I have gotten this exact thing to work on other portions of my site but cannot here.

The exact problem happens when the `setup` method gets called and which then in turns calls another method that relies on an ID that is passed in. However, I don't pass in the ID when I have the link_to in the dropdown menu because I don't want to call setup.

Here is the relevant code:

setup.html.erb :

```
  <div class="dropdown-menu aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton"" >
    <% @days.each do |d|%>
      <%= link_to "Go to #{d}", weeks_draw_day_path(:test => d), :class=>'dropdown-item' %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

weeks_controller.rb: I removed most of the `setup` code because it wasn't useful. I did keep the param lookup with the id and the subsequent call to a helper method that crashes because I never pass in that id on the link_to in the above view.

```
class WeeksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_week, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  def schedule
    week, start, finish = get_set_of_weeks()
    for i in 0...week.length
      Week.check_insert_week(week[i], start[i], finish[i])
    end
  end


  def setup
    # Gets the id of the current week
    @w = Week.find_by_id(params[:id])
    # Gets a DB friendly start of week 

  end

  def draw_day
    byebug
    logger.info "Sup"
  end



  def week_lookup_controller(id)
    Week.week_lookup_model_lit(id)
  end


  helper_method :week_lookup_controller

  private

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def week_params
      params.fetch(:week, {})
    end
end
```

routes.rb :I only have the "weeks" controller routes listed here as I don't believe the others are relevant.

```
  ########### Week actions #############
  get 'weeks/schedule'
  get '/weeks/:id', to: 'weeks#setup', as: 'weeks_setup'
  get 'weeks/draw_day'

  resources :weeks, only: [:schedule, ] do
    get :schedule, on: :collection
  end
```

As you can see I have `byebug` in the draw_day controller method. This never gets executed. Let me know if I can provide any more useful information, thanks for the help!

Comment: Try adding `as: :draw_day` after your `get 'weeks/draw_day'` route (might also need to specify `to:`). You can see what the route is currently named by doing something like `rake routes | grep draw_day` from the command line,

Comment: @dinjas Without your suggestion I get this with `weeks_draw_day GET /weeks/draw_day(.:format) weeks#draw_day)`. With your suggestion I get the same exact thing except `weeks` is no longer appended in the first "draw_day". I changed the view to match the new route and was given the same error in the helper method that is called.

Comment: ah sorry, I misread your original explanation. try just moving the `weeks/dray_day` route above your `/weeks/:id` route. Also if you watch your server logs when you click the link, you should be able to see something happen.

Comment: @dinjas it works when I place the route above the id, thank you! I would like to figure out why if possible. Without the fix, the console shows a GET request for `weeks/draw_day`. Then it says `Processing by WeeksController#setup as HTML` that setup is the page that I want to be navigating away from. With the fix the proper controller action is shown on the console `WeeksController#draw_day as HTML`

Comment: When Rails tries to find a route to maps your request to a `controller#action`, it uses the first route that matches. When you have the `/weeks/:id` route first, and you try to visit `/weeks/draw_day`, it matches `'draw_day'` as the `:id` param in your `/weeks/:id` route and sends you off to `weeks#setup` with `params[:id]` set to `'draw_day'`.